# Parse.com How to keep subscriptions channels between installations?

Tags: android, parse-platform

For example if a user to "alpha", "beta", "gamma" channels uninstall the application and reinstall subscribe or erasing data from the application as I restore your subscriptions

Comment: How did you implemented it? I'm stuck at same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

You can save channels that a user subscribed on in a `ParseUser` object. Next time when the user will authorize, you can retrieve these channels and restore user's subscriptions.

Comment: can you provide an example or a link in the documentation to indicate the process?